# overridePendingTransition with code generated animation

Tags: android

I'm creating a custom animation in run time, and want to override a pending transition with this new animation, how can I do this?

Comment: You cannot, the transition animations need to resources that can be passed through to `ActivityManagerNative`. Custom run-time animations cant be used with `overridePendingTransition`.

Comment: "static" animations in `res/anim`.